# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when getting Wordpress posts in Phonegap app

Tags: wordpress, cordova

Hopefully someone can help me to resolve the following problem while developing a mobile app in phonegap. I am attempting to read posts from a wordpress installation but I get this error when I run my index.html page on chrome

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

I have JSON-API plugin installed in wordpress and when I navigate to the page I want I can view it ok. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function readSinglePost (url,target_div) {
        var URL = url//+"&callback=?";
            console.log(URL);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: URL,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                jQuery(target_div).append("<h1>"+data.post.title+"</h1>");
                jQuery(target_div).append(data.post.content);jQuery(target_div).
                append("<small>"+data.post.date+"</small>");
                console.log(data.post.content);
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "http://www.example.com/api/get_post/?json=get_post&dev=1&id=5486";
        var target_div = "#contents";

        readSinglePost(url, target_div);
    });
</script>
</header>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="title"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPDATE***
In response to Jamie below

**Raw Request**

```
GET /api/get_post/?json=get_post&dev=1&id=5486 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Raw Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 16:51:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix)
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=f6308c2732752bbb1149b345018bdf68; path=/
Set-Cookie: wc_session_cookie_a111a960a9b29354988b3de48943ad50=IRhSF41ZHIBHMA3mmCCSSjdOSxqXf2wj%7C%7C1373215910%7C%7C1373212310%7C%7Cd472ed970a72ba78e8b2c836a1d8b2cc; expires=Sun, 07-Jul-2013 16:51:50 GMT; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: woocommerce_items_in_cart=0; expires=Fri, 05-Jul-2013 15:51:50 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: woocommerce_cart_hash=0; expires=Fri, 05-Jul-2013 15:51:50 GMT; path=/
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset: UTF-8
Content-Length: 57602
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the problem that you are running into is commonly referred to as Cross Origin Security. Basically, most web-browsers will not allow you to pull in content from servers outside your own, unless the server says it is ok.  To do this, the server needs to see an acceptable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the headers.

The good news is that this is fairly easy to fix, as Bowdenweb points out in [How to Enable cors in WordPress](http://bowdenweb.com/wp/2011/05/how-to-enable-cors-in-wordpress.html).

You only need to add the appropriate header to the `headers.php` file, like so

```
<?php /** @package WordPress @subpackage Default_Theme  **/
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Update 1**

As ILI pointed out, there is a plugin for Wordpress called [WordPress-Cross-Domain-Plugin](https://github.com/jacopotarantino/WordPress-Cross-Domain-Plugin) which resolved this issue for him.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for your response. I have pasted the code you suggested into the top of my header.php file in the theme that I am using but I am still having the same problem, any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend getting a copy of [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) for Windows. This will act as a proxy, and allow you to inspect all of the web traffic. You can then see all of the requests and responses, which will likely allow you to provide additional information.

Comment: Hi Jamie, I've had a look with Fiddler2 and nothing obvious appears unfortunately still getting the error.

Comment: What result code are you getting? 200?  Would you be able to post the Raw Request and Response headers?

Comment: Hi yes it is 200. I have edited the question to include the Raw Request and Response headers.. I hope they are the correct ones from Fiddler. Thanks for your help

Comment: There appears to be a problem with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, as it's not showing up in the response (which it must to make this work).

Comment: Ok thanks Jamie, getting places! Not sure why manually adding the code to the header didn't work but I found this plugin that did the trick https://github.com/jacopotarantino/WordPress-Cross-Domain-Plugin. My page remains blank but when I check the error console I get the following Object {status: "ok", post: Object, previous_url: ... followed by the content of my post. Any final ideas on how to display this?

Comment: Sorry ignore the final comment it was my div tags in the body content. Many thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't allow cross domain calls in ajax by default. Jamie Starke gives you the answer. Maybe try to use `$.support.cors = true;` with JQuery. Anyway, a Phonegap app can do ajax cross domain requests. If you can't, check your config.xml http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: try `<access origin="*"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
in plist file add

 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>


<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
         <dict>
             <key>yourdominename.com</key>
                    <dict>
                      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
                      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                      <true/>
                      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
                      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                      <true/>
                      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
                      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                </dict>
          </dict>
</dict>
```

in config file

```
 <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are still having problems with Access-Control-Allow-Origin despite having wildcarded their config.xml might like to check this out if they're using Jellybean.  From what I can gather it is fixed in the newest version of phonegap but installation of the newest version is beyond my limited talents!

Read this: [Phonegap/Cordova App breaks in Jelly Bean - Access-Control-Allow-Origin and setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409440/phonegap-cordova-app-breaks-in-jelly-bean-access-control-allow-origin-and-seta)