# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing content doesn't load

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain

My wordpress-installation is on my webspace with the domain finalarts.de and everything works fine.
I have added my 2nd domain to my page floriangampert.de, but when I access the site via the 2nd domain the content doesn't load.

I think the problem is the Cross-Original Resource Sharing policy:

```
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
```

I have tried to add:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

into the .htaccess, but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top of your header add

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
?>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491185/access-control-allow-origin-error-when-getting-wordpress-posts-in-phonegap-app) question refers.